# Ability to choose multiple files in the file browser using the browse button

Tags: html, file-upload

When I click on the browse button `input type='file'`, I get to choose only one file at a time.  Is there any way to choose multiple files?  Also is there any way to see the files in thumbnail view?

Comment: @Martin: you're totally wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can choose multiple files only with flash plugins like [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/), for thumbnails you'd need a java applet

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is. In [HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.file.html#input.file.attrs.multiple) `<input type="file">` can have attribute `"multiple"`

Old article about that: http://rakaz.nl/2009/08/uploading-multiple-files-using-html5.html

[Example.](http://www.3site.eu/jstests/upload/) (works in Firefox and Chrome/Iron)

Answer (score 0):

No way for multiple files that I know of but you can dynamically add file controls to the page if they need to do multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flash for your file uploads. Flash will allow you to open a file dialog that will allow multiple file selections.

Google "[flash multiple file uploader](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=flash+multiple+file+uploader)" and you will see many examples.