# How to create a file input which allows multiple files to be selected?

Tags: php, html, file, upload

how do I create a file input which allows multiple files to be selected and uploaded?
It seems that    `<input type="file" name="fileinput">`
allows only 1 file to be selected at a time, while the input on http://filetolink.com/ (for example) let's the user select multiple files. How is this done and how do I go about processing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not to look at filetolink code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ability to choose multiple files in the file browser using the browse button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389768/ability-to-choose-multiple-files-in-the-file-browser-using-the-browse-button)

Comment: @Col. if they use Flash, the SWF object is useless for him unless he has a flash decompiler

Comment: @daemon one don't have to decompile SWF to use it. Just google and download. it's not that hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML 5 input element can do this, but it's not widely supported yet. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389768/ability-to-choose-multiple-files-in-the-file-browser-using-the-browse-button), the second answer)

Flash based uploaders like [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org) and Uploadify have this, but as said they need Flash, and they have a different philosophy behind how they work.

Comment: Ah well it's for personal use and the only browsers I have installed are Firefox and Chrome, so the HTML5 could come in handy.

Comment: yeah, in code for layy ppl: `<input type="file" name="uploads" multiple />`

Comment: Question: Why got this answer +2? If we look @ the "tags" and the question, we might see that the user wants to have a html/php, a clean, solution. Flash is 3rd party software which is mostly available but not the perfect answer for this problem. You should up vote answers promoting HTML+JS, and I do not mean experimental HTML, HTML5 isn't standard yet.

Comment: @daemonfire if I understand the OP correctly, he wants people to be able to select *multiple files at once*, which is something no pure HTML+JS solution can do yet.

Answer (score 2):

there are plenty of javascript extensions to achieve the task you asked. Try to check it with [jQuery repository](http://jquery.com/).

One example you may find here: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/

Comment: Thank you for your helpful links, I'll have a look! (Don't know much about JS though :-( )

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the JQuery [**Uploadify**](http://www.uploadify.com/) component component, works consistently across browsers. Here is a [**demo**](http://www.uploadify.com/demo/).

Answer (score 0):

It is done using Flash which assumes that the client browser has Flash installed and enabled. The standard HTML `<input type="file">` allows only a single file. You may find the [SWFUpload flash component](http://www.swfupload.org/) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Possible by using Javascript and HTML4, you may use this jQuery Plugin (http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/).

Answer (score 0):

Multiple file uploader using mootool:
http://the-stickman.com/files/mootools/multiupload/

SwfUpload: It uses flash
If you want to get an idea how to process the uploaded file checkout this link
[sample php code](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/source/browse/swfupload/#swfupload/trunk/samples/samples/php)

Another one is [fancyupload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/) (uses flash and mootools)

Uploading using an HTML5 compliant browser (Firefox 3.6, Chrome 3.0 or Safari 4)
This is a new method of uploading files is not widely supported by all browsers.
See an example using php at [link](http://verens.com/2009/12/28/multiple-file-uploads-using-html5/)

http://www.uploadify.com/ is also another great multiple file uploader.
The user can upload all the files at once using ctrl + clicking on all of the files